# Can an ordered set of vectors guarantee that the first half are larger in real and imaginary components than the second half?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, complex-numbers, vectors

Recently, on one of my problem sets I wrote a solution to a question that I feel should be correct. Me and my supervisor spoke about it but could not come up with a way to show my method worked or did not.

Question: Red sweets and blue sweets are randomly distributed across the 99 bags. Can you always pick 50 bags in such a way that you have at least half of the red sweets, and at least half of the blue sweets?

My attempt: Let each bag be represented by $ z_k=r_k+b_k i$ with $\sum_{k=1}^nr_i=1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^nb_i=1$ 
ie, $r_i$ and $b_i$ represent the proportion of total red/ blue sweets. 
Note: only considering case where $r_k<0.5, b_k<0.5$ $∀k$ if not true then problem is trivial.
Now, Take $$|0.5+0.5i-z_k|$$ and order $z_k$ from smallest to largest value of above. such that $$|0.5+0.5i-z_k|\le|0.5+0.5i-z_{k+1}|$$
My claim; If we let $$u=\sum_{k=1}^{50}z_k ,v=\sum_{k=51}^{99}z_k$$
Then by the way we ordered $z_k$ $$Re(v)\le0.5, Im(v)\le0.5$$
and thus $u$ has $Re(u)>0.5$ and $Im(u)>0.5$ as required.
My question; Is this correct/ valid. If so, how do I prove that $v$ lies within the $(0.5,0.5)$ square
Note: I am a 1A student. I know how to solve this problem using other means but am still interested in this method.

Comment: What is a "1A" student? Do you know what the Pigeonhole principle is? (Combinatorics seems like a much more useful tag than number-theory, hence the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach (as is) doesnt' work.

Here is a counter example.

Let 50 bags contain $\frac{1}{50}$ of the blue sweets each.
Let 49 bags contain $ \frac{1}{49}$ of the red sweets each.

Then, your selection will pick up all 50 bags with blue sweets, giving you $ Re(u) = 1, Im (u) = 0$.

Comment: Thank, I cant believe I didn't look at this. I wonder if there is a nice geometrical/ vector based approach to solving this question? But for now I think that it's probably more effort than its worth =P

Comment: @JoeMcglynn I'm not aware of an (essentially) vector proof of this statement. The proofs that I'm aware of essentially boil down to showing that some consecutive set of 50 bags (regardless of how we arrange them) will satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 0):

With odd $n\gg 0$, take

- three bags with $\frac13i$
- $n-3$ bags with $\frac1{n-3}$

The first three are closer to $\frac12+\frac12i$, hence are picked into $u$. That means that $\frac{n-1}2$ of the latter make your $v$ and give it a total real part of $\frac{n-1}{2n-6}=\frac12+\frac{1}{n-3}>\frac12$.